# AnnotationProcessor from a dependency does not gets executed

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have a jar file (name: test-annotation-processor.jar) which has the annotation-processors declared. The annotation-processors have the following format:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("*") 
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_11) 
@AutoService(Processor.class) 
@SuppressWarnings("unused") 
public class TestGenerator extends AbstractProcessor {
    
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        //Searches for classes marked with specific annotations (example: @TestAnnotation)
        //Generates code classes
    } 
}

//Annotation Class 
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
@Target({ElementType.TYPE}) 
public @interface TestAnnotation {   
    //Supporting methods 
}
```

Following is the build section of pom.xml in this project:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>foo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>test-annotation-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <annotationProcessors>
                    <annotationProcessor>TestGenerator</annotationProcessor>
                </annotationProcessors>
                <failOnError>true</failOnError>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The above jar is used as a dependency in another project’s pom.xml as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>test.annotation.processor</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>${version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Whenever I create a new build using Maven (using **maven clean install**), the annotation processor kicks in and the code gets generated in the folder at the following path:

> ${project-root}/target/generated-sources/annotations/

I am trying to migrate this pom.xml to a build.gradle file. My build.gradle.kts has the following structure:

```
plugins {
    id("maven-publish")
    id("java-library")
}

dependencies {
    implementation("test.annotation.processor:test-annotation-processor:version")
    annotationProcessor("test.annotation.processor:test-annotation-processor:version")
   //Other dependencies
}
```

When I try to create a build using **gradle clean build**, I can see the folder structure which gets generated but unfortunately the folder is empty and no code gets generated. I tried to attach a debug point to the annotation-processor but was never able to reach it. I am guessing that the annotation-processor does gets executed in this case:

> ${project-root}/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main

I tried to check if the annotation-processing jar is available in the classpath using the command:

> ./gradlew dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath

and I found them to be available.

In Intellij, I was also able to check the presence of this jar in the external dependencies section. It had the following structure:

```
| - test-annotation-processor.jar
    | - package
        | - Annotation Processor Classes
    | - META-INF
      - Other packages
      - services
         - javax.annotation.processing.Processor
```

The file javax.annotation.processing.Processor contains the fully qualified name of the annotation-processor class.

Can someone please help me with this issue? I am not sure what I am missing here.